# Entity States in a web application and in a desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web

When we're using Entity Framework, an entity maybe in one of the following states: Added, Unchanged, Modified, Deleted or Detached. In a desktop application, state changes are typically set *automatically* but in a web application we have to *manually* set the entity state. 
I want to know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the state of entities is tracked by Entity Framework.

In web applications however, when an entity is retrieved from the database, it gets sent to the browser and Entity Framework can no longer "see" the entity and it can no longer track any changes made to it.

Therefore you would have to manually tell Entity Framework if an entity coming in from a web request (ex. from a form post) should be treated as a new one (and should be inserted) or if it corresponds to an existing entity on the database (and should be updated) or if it should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's required to track the changes, to find out what you've changed value on attached entity, and what actions entity framework should make with that attached entity.Setting state manually is important in case of detached entities but its not required all the time, if you need more details on this then you should post some queries or sample code on your issue.